# How to use composer with docker-compose?

Tags: php, symfony, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am configuring the `docker-compose.yml` file and I want to run a PHP stack that contains Elastic, Redis, Symfony, and composer.

Now the problem that I have is, that I don't know how can I use composer with docker because some features of composer need to have PHP and some extension. I don't want to build a new image and install Nginx and PHP and composer and extension of PHP on it, I won't to have all of them in a disparate image.

What I have tried so far its this:

```
version : '2'

services:
  nginx:
    image: tutum/nginx
    ports:
        - "80:80"
    volumes:        
        - ./nginx/default:/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
        - ./nginx/default:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
        - ./logs/nginx-error.log:/var/log/nginx/error.log
        - ./logs/nginx-access.log:/var/log/nginx/access.log
        - ./app:/usr/share/nginx/html

  phpfpm:
      image: php:fpm
      ports:
          - 9000:9000
      volumes:      
          - ./app:/usr/share/nginx/html
          
  composer:
      image: composer/composer:php7
      command: install
      volumes: 
        - ./app:/app

  elastic2.4.4:
    image: elasticsearch:2.4.4    
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    volumes:
      - ./esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data

  redis:
    image: redis:3.2
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
```

but this won't install dependencies.

Comment: have you look at this https://github.com/maxpou/docker-symfony

Answer (score 6):

I set up my `docker-compose.yml` file so one docker instance would use the `composer/composer` image and execute `composer install` within a shared container. All of the other images would then be able to access the vendor directory that composer created. The tricky part was realizing that the `composer/composer` image assumes that the `composer.json` file will be in an `/app` directory. I had to override this behavior by specifying my shared container as the `working_dir` instead:

```
version: '3'

services:
  #=====================#
  # nginx proxy service #
  #=====================#
  nginx_proxy:
    image: nginx:alpine
    networks:
      - test_network
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      # self-signed testing wildcard ssl certificate
      - "./certs:/certs"
      # proxy needs access to static files
      - "./site1/public:/site1/public"
      - "./site2/public:/site2/public"
      # proxy needs nginx configuration files
      - "./site1/site1.test.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site1.test.conf"
      - "./site2/site2.test.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site2.test.conf"
    container_name: nginx_proxy

  #===============#
  # composer.test #
  #===============#
  composer.test:
    image: composer/composer
    networks:
      - test_network
    ports:
      - "9001:9000"
    volumes:
      - "./composer:/composer"
    container_name: composer.test
    working_dir: /composer
    command: install

  #============#
  # site1.test #
  #============#
  site1.test:
    build: ./site1
    networks:
      - test_network
    ports:
      - "9002:9000"
    environment:
      - "VIRTUAL_HOST=site1.test"
    volumes:
      - "./composer:/composer"
      - "./site1:/site1"
    container_name: site1.test

  #============#
  # site2.test #
  #============#
  site2.test:
    build: ./site2
    networks:
      - test_network
    ports:
      - "9003:9000"
    environment:
      - "VIRTUAL_HOST=site2.test"
    volumes:
      - "./composer:/composer"
      - "./site2:/site2"
    container_name: site2.test

# networks
networks:
  test_network:
```

Here is how the directory structure looks:

```
certs
    test.crt
    test.key
composer
    composer.json
site1
    app
    public
    Dockerfile
    site1.test.conf
site2
    app
    public
    Dockerfile
    site2.test.conf
docker-compose.yml
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look at `composer/composer:php7` `Dockerfile`, then you will see, that it is based on `php:7.0-alpine` and it doesn't seem like `fpm` is included. So, you could use `composer/composer:php7` as base image to install `php-fpm` on top of it.

So, since you do the mapping of your project in all three containers, running `composer install` in one container should result in the changes be visible in all three containers.

Me personally, I do not see a point in segregating PHP and nginx into 2 different containers, because one is highly dependable on another. And mapping your app into both containers is also a perfect example of nonsense. That's why I maintain my own public build of nginx+php Docker image. You can check it out [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/flexbox/centos-php72/). There are more builds with more flavors. And they all come with composer inside.

Comment: That image would be nice to use - but there's no doc as far as I can tell; what's the web user? what is the path to web root? etc...